# How to pass hashmap KEY to spinner1 and its corresponding VALUES to spinner2 android

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap, android-arrayadapter

I am fetching values from XML values from web.....in below code I am getting values correctly but I am not able to pass the KEY to spinneer1 and when spinner1 is changed its corresponding VALUES in spinner2 will be changed accordingly.

**In LOGCAT I am getting values like this which i have to pass to both the spinners**

```
{
Jackfruit=[Cabbage, Kesar, Amond], 
Date=[van, hall, Brinjal], 
Brinjal=[Cabbage, Kesar, Amond]
}
```

So,if **Jackfruit** is selected in spinner1 then- **Cabbage, Kesar, Amond** should diplay in spinner2

**The above logcat I am getting from the below code of the UPDATE-3 of the MainActivity.java**

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:AAAAA");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

    String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:W").item(0).getTextContent();

    if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) {
        values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>());

    }
    String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:R").item(0).getTextContent();
    values.get(awValue).add(arValue);
}
Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + values);
```

**And the whole code of MainActivity.java is**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> title2;
    Button button;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner2;
    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    //private EditText toDateEtxt;

    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    //private DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog;

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter2;
    Map<String, List<String>> values = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        title2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                parse();

                from_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title);
                from_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                from_adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title2);
                from_adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


                spinner.setAdapter(from_adapter);
                spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);


            }

            private Object from_adapter(int i) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        });


    }



    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ""+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

    protected void parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "WEB URL");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:AAAA");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                // get the a:W value
                String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:W").item(0).getTextContent();
                // add the above value in our map  as key if it isn't present in the map, this key will 
                // have a list associated with it in which ALL the values for a:R will be stored, if 
                // the awValue key is present then you just add the new a:R value to its list 
                if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) {
                    values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                // also add the value pointed by a:R to the list associated with a:W
                String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:R").item(0).getTextContent();
                values.get(awValue).add(arValue);
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + arValue);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:W");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:R");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                title.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:AAAA");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList2.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:R");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         
                title2.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title);
            title = new ArrayList<String>(set);
            // Collection<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(months);
            Set<String> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title2);
            title2 = new ArrayList<String>(set2);
            System.out.println("list are");
            System.out.println(set);
            System.out.println("list 2 are");
            System.out.println(set2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    }
```

***How to pass the value of key to spinner1 one and its related VALUES to spinner2 on click of spinner***

**Changes-1**

From the below code if i change the spinner1 value then its correspondence value is toasted correctly i.e if **Jackfruit** is selected then **Cabbage, Kesar, Amond** is toasted correctly

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        String lang_Name = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        List<String> lang_Key = values.get(lang_Name);
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ""+lang_Key,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

***and I want the toasted values to be pass to spinner2 dynamically on dependent to spinner1.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the spinner1 value (HashMap key), in onItemSelected, and get it's corresponding values, give the spinner2 adapter the values you got, and refresh it.

```
from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try this code;

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    String lang_Name = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    List<String> lang_Key = values.get(lang_Name);
    from_adapter2.clear():
    for(String s : lang_Key){
          from_adapter2.insert(s, from_adapter2.getCount());
    }
    from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: when I am selecting the spinner1 value it correctly toasting the values which i want to pass to spinner2 and that value I want to pass it to the spinner2 one after other in drop down that i am unable to do...please see in Changes-1 code

Comment: yaa its showing but when I first launches the app it shows all the other values also but when i change spinner1 then it shows the selected correct lists i.e. at first display it shows all the default values

Comment: onCreate, before setting the adapter in the spinner(spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);), empty the adapter. from_adapter2.clear();

Comment: If the answer was helpful and solved your problem, don't forget to accept it. Any other question, feel free to ask

Comment: it still showing the default list of full data in spinner2..... did like this .....spinner.setAdapter(from_adapter);
    from_adapter2.clear();
    spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109141/discussion-between-android-putra-and-ricardo-barroca).

Comment: You also need to add this line: from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); after from_adapter2.clear();

Comment: the problem is still the same i did like this .....spinner.setAdapter(from_adapter);
    from_adapter2.clear();
    from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);......and the problem is that if person selects that default list values from spinner2 it actually crashes the app

Comment: need help for this plz?

Comment: check the chat please http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109141/discussion-between-android-putra-and-ricardo-barroca